# Varnish caching for on demand domains / Multitenancy

Tags: docker, caching, cdn, varnish, caddy

I have been trying to setup custom CDN using Caddy and varnish. The idea is to generate on demand SSL certificate and then pass it to varnish which further sends it to the backend server which is a nodejs application. If the request matches then varnish returns  the cache results otherwise fetches new data.
The working is described in the diagram
[flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrmO2.png)

Here are the respective files:
**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  web:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false
    driver: bridge

services:
 caddy:
    image: caddy
    container_name: caddy
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
      - $PWD/site:/srv
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    networks:
      - web

 varnish:
    container_name: varnish
    image: varnish:stable
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - $PWD/data/varnish/default.vcl:/etc/varnish/default.vcl
    networks:
      - web
      - internal
volumes:
  caddy_data:
    external: true
  caddy_config:
```

**Caddyfile**

```
{
    on_demand_tls {
        ask      https://check-domain-URL
    }
}

https:// {

tls {
    on_demand
}                          

reverse_proxy varnish:80 {
                header_up Host {host}  # Won't work with another value or transparent preset
                header_up X-Forwarded-Host {host}
                header_up X-Real-IP {remote}
                header_up X-Forwarded-For {remote}
                header_up X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}
                header_up X-Caddy-Forwarded 1
                header_down Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000"
}

header /_next/static/* {
Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable"
}
}

:8080 {
reverse_proxy backend-address:3000
}
```

**default.vcl**

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "caddy";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_deliver
{
    # Insert Diagnostic header to show Hit or Miss
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
        set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
    }
    else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }

}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.ttl = 10s;
    set beresp.grace = 1h;

}
```

Everything is working fine

1. SSL certificates are generating
2. Proxy is working
3. Varnish is returning results
4. Proxy is fetching backend

The only problem is that Varnish Cache is always `miss`, the one thing that it is supposed to do
I have tried all means, but it looks like the varnish sees every request as a new request.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to understand why you receive the cache misses, you need to understand the built-in VCL.

This is the VCL code that is executed behind the scenes. Please have a look at the following tutorial that explains this: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl/.

### Built-in VCL cache bypass summary

I'd like to summarize the standard situations where Varnish doesn't cache:

1. When the request method is not `GET` or `HEAD`
2. When the request contains an `Authorization` header
3. When the request contains a `Cookie` header
4. When the response contains a `Set-Cookie` header
5. When the response TTL is zero because of the `Expires` header or `max-age=0` or `s-maxage=0` in the `Cache-Control` header
6. When the response contains `private`, `no-cache` or `no-store` in the `Cache-Control` header
7. When there's a `Vary: *` response header

### Inspecting cache miss/bypass with varnishlog

An easy way to figure out why a cache miss occurs or why the cache is bypassed is by using `varnishlog`.

You can run the following command to check logs for the homepage:

```
sudo varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"
```

> Please change `/` into the desire URL.

### Writing VCL to compensate

If your application doesn't behave according to the built-in VCL specifications, you'll have to write some VCL code to compensate for that.

In most cases that is stripping off tracking cookies or defining which URL patterns should bypass the cache while forcing cache lookups on all other pages.

> Have a look at the logs to figure out what's what and if you need help, just add a log transaction to your question and I'll help you out.

Comment: thanks for the resonse, in this case it was the cookie case